# How to increase the heap size when using hadoop jar?

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, bigdata, heap-memory

I am running a program with the `hadoop jar` command. However, to make that program run faster, I need to increase Hadoop's heap size. I tried the following, but it didn't have any effect (I have hadoop version 2.5), even on the same terminal.

```
export HADOOP_HEAPSIZE=16384
export HADOOP_OPTS="-Xmx16g"
```

Another way I reckon is to add the following to the mapred-site.xml file, but I am unfortunately not the admin, so can't do it.

```
<property>
    <name>mapred.child.java.opts</name>
    <value>-Xmx16384m</value>
</property>
```

Is there any other method as well to do this?

Comment: increasing heap size is not a solution to run program faster. You can try alternate way like increasing Mapper, Reducer or optimizing your code.

Comment: The author of the program said to increase the heap size. I am not the author of that program, just the user.

Comment: add `-Dmapred.child.java.opts=-Xmx16384m` to your hadoop jar command

Comment: Didn't work as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this problem by modifying the HADOOP_CLIENT_OPTS environment variable, as shown below.

```
export HADOOP_CLIENT_OPTS="-Xmx16g $HADOOP_CLIENT_OPTS"
```

Note that the program I am using runs only on the Master node. In other words, its not a distributed application.

Answer (score 1):

A way to increase the heap size when using Hadoop jar that works for me:

```
HADOOP_CLIENT_OPTS="-XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit -Xmx16384m" hadoop jar parquetExample.jar
```

as you can see you set the environment variable's value (works for other environment variables too, in this case I am setting the max size to `16384m`) in the same line and before the `hadoop jar` command.